# insert value into array in while loop

Tags: perl

I have one array that has 10 records, I need to read each row and store it to another array. I tried below code but its not working as expected

Please give some suggestion for this.

```
while (my @row = $processed_sql->fetchrow_array)
        {
            #print "sq_no: $row[0] hie_key:$row[1] today: $row[2] table_name: $row[3] batch_id: $row[4] table_count: $row[5] pre_count: $row[6]\n";

            my $table_name = $row[3];
            my $batch_id = $row[4];
            my $table_count = $row[5];
            my $pre_count=$row[6];

            #my $nvalue;

            #print "$table_name,$table_count\n";


        if($table_count >= $pre_count)

        {

            @no_issue = ($row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6]);

            print "value is greater @no_issue\n";

        }
        else
        {
            print "jkdlkjfa\n";
        }


        }
        print "@no_issue\n";
```

If I print the value with in the loop am getting correct answer but when I print out side of loop then am getting only one record from the array.

Answer (score 1):

The following line overwrites the whole array:

```
@no_issue = ($row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6]);
```

If you don't want to overwrite ti, but add values, use [push](http://p3rl.org/push).

```
push @no_issue, [ @row[ 3 .. 6 ] ];
```

This will create an array of arrays, so you need to dereference the inner arrays when printing:

```
for my $line (@no_issue) {
    print join(' ', @$line), "\n";
}
```

which is almost equivalent to more succint

```
print map "@$_\n", @no_issue;
```

Comment: Its working fine, but i dont need array of array i need to store that single array. so that i can able to copy only some value from that array to file.

Comment: I don't understand. Please, provide [Simple Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: in this when i print @no_issue array that showing like array reference(i.e) ARRAY(0x217a880) ARRAY(0x217a8f8) ARRAY(0x217a988) ARRAY(0x217aa18) ARRAY(0x217aaa8) ARRAY(0x217ab38), but i dont need this. if i print the array that should print actual value of array.

Comment: is it make you understand?

Comment: No. Show us a sample input and expected output.

Comment: @row=(laksh,1,3,2
vij,1,2,3
kar,1,2,3); assume this is my input.

Comment: @row=(laksh,1,3,2
vij,1,2,3
kar,1,2,3); assume this is my input.

My Output should be
@no_issue = (laksh,3,2
vij,2,3
kar,2,3) so that i will be print this to file.

if i print $no_issue[0] ,$no_issue[1],$no_issue[2] then i should get the related value of that array element

Comment: @PANDIALAKSHMANAN: So where's the problem? Do you need to move the print statement into the loop?